# Unable to query services with systemctl is-enabled

Tags: systemd, debian-jessie

On a Debian Jessie, systemd looks working quite fine:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable shibd.service 
Synchronizing state for shibd.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d shibd defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d shibd enable
```

'start', 'stop' and 'status' command all work.

But is-enabled command fails:

```
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled shibd.service 
Failed to get unit file state for shibd.service: No such file or directory
```

On the other hand, with sssd, ssh also 'is-enabled' works:

```
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled sssd.service 
enabled
```

I would like to solve this issue because puppet tries to re-enable the services at each run.

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/

Comment: correct. As for ntp it is  #635752; for apche2 #798430. If you turn your comment into an answer I can mark as accepetd. In the meanwhile, thank you.

Comment: I face this for `ufw`